# Changing <head> ection with Volt

Tags: voltrb

I've just started playing with Volt, and looked this up on the docs, couldn't find the answer:

I want to add a viewport meta tag on my project's  section, but I can't find out how to alter it.

Could anyone shed some light on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Yea, you can change config/base/index.html  This renders at an earlier stage right now, so you can't do bindings.  (It's rendered as erb right now)  We have the ability to render templates to strings, so the plan is to make it so all of the initial rendering process is done with volt templates.  We just haven't gotten around to it yet :-)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the file on "config/base/index.html" (Volt 0.9.3)

Gonna leave this here, in case someone else needs it in the future =]